# Java: Creating New Strings During Runtime to Edit

Tags: java, string, methods, runtime

I'm creating a Mad Lib generator in Java. If you know what a Mad Lib is, this will be easier to understand. Also, I'm new to Java, so bear with me here. I want to make it so that each Mad Lib only asks for the number of adjectives, nouns, etc. that are in that specific one. For example, Mad Lib 1 may have 3 nouns, while Mad Lib 2 has 5 nouns. Is there a way to write a separate method to be run X times, creating X new strings (for the player to enter X nouns), and giving each string a different name? Just giving the strings names like nounA, nounB, nounC, or noun1, noun2, noun3 would be perfect. I need the final story to be able to differentiate between them. It will be really nice if each time I decide to add another Mad Lib to my program to just be able to loop an addNoun() method 8 times instead of writing

```
String nounA = scan.next();
System.out.print("\f");
String nounB = scan.next();
System.out.print("\f");
```

...and so on every time for each part of speech. I have not yet learned about arrays, and I think this may have a solution involving that. Like I said, I'm new to Java, so if you try to show me anything advanced, please explain it in a way that I can understand it or find a simpler way to do it.

Comment: In case you 'feel' that arrays might help here, why don't you look into that? Also check the Java Collections Framework: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/

Comment: I looked into arrays a bit more right after posting this, which was probably not the order that I should have done that in. The answer I chose confirmed what I learned after searching, so thank you for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the count of nouns, say, in `int nounCount`, use arrays like this:

```
String[] nouns = new String[nounCount]; // Create an array
for (int i = 0; i < nouns.length; i++) {
    nouns[i] = scan.next(); // Set each item
}
```

Then you would be able to access different words as `noun[0]`, `noun[1]`, etc. You're likely to use loops and store index of selected noun somewhere though.

See also: [Java arrays tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correct then you need to use `ArrayList` and `HashMap` to achieve this:

First you can create `ArrayList` of `String` to store X nouns. An ex: of `Arraylist` is:

```
  List<String> nouns = new ArrayList<String>();
  nouns.add('nounA'); // add related noun
  //or
  String nounStr = 'new Noun'
  nouns.add(nounStr);
```

Then you can categorise particular *nouns* by `HashMap`

```
HashMap<String, List<String> > nounCategory = new HashMap<String, List<String> >();
nounCategory.put('madLib1', 'nouns'); // add all list with a unique key madLib1 ...
```

To learn more about using `List` and `HashMap` read reference [List:here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and [HashMap:here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)